# My javascript code is not working properly

Tags: javascript

i have this code , its takes a number and generate that number into a card 
my problem is that the code generates 2 cards instead of one 
in the first card i see a "> at the start and when i put my mouse over says tagged with: div class=
and the tooltip isnt working

the result must be a card with details and if you use the tooltip takes you to more details

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  function make_card_list(card, el) {

    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="card" id="card_' + card.id + '">';
    html += '<span class="card_id">#superhero' + card.id + '</span>';
    html += '<div class="card_header">';

    html += '<span data-name="name">' + card.name + '</span>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="abilities-details">' + card.abilities + '</div>';
    html += '<div data-tooltip="' + '" class="card_picture" data-name="img" style="background-image: url(' + card.img + ');text-align:center;color:black;line-height: 150px;">';

    var poster_data = $(el).parent().parent().find('.postprofile textarea').val();
    if (poster_data) {

      poster_data = JSON.parse(poster_data);

      if (jQuery.inArray(Number(card.id), poster_data.cards) == -1) {
        html += '<div class="nocard">This card does not exit.</div>';
      }
    }

    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="card_text">';
    html += '<span data-name="txt">';
    html += card.txt;
    html += '</span>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="abilities"></div>';
    html += '<div class="card_bottom card_stats">';
    html += '<div class="card_stats_inside">';

    if (card.strength != "") {
      html += '<p>Strength: <span data-name="strength">' + card.strength + '</span></p>';
    };
    if (card.energy != "") {
      html += '<p>Energy: <span data-name="damage">' + card.energy + '</span></p>';
    };
    if (card.skills != "") {
      html += '<p>Skills: <span data-name="damage">' + card.skills + '</span></p>';
    };
    if (card.speed != "") {
      html += '<p>Speed: <span data-name="damage">' + card.speed + '</span></p>';
    };

    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    if (card.type == 16 || card.type == 14 || card.type == 31 || card.type == 27) {

      html += '<div class="card_bottom card_slots" style="width:335px;">';
      html += '<div class="card_slots_inside">';

      if (card.inv > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

          if (i < card.inv) {
            html += '<span style="background:#9d1717;" class="card_inv"></span>';
          } else {
            html += '<span class="card_inv"></span>';
          }
        }
      }

      html += '<span style="background: #57b371;" class="card_slot"></span>';
    } else {

      html += '<div class="card_bottom card_middle">';
      html += '<div class="card_stats_inside">';

      if (card.enemies != "") {
        html += '<p>Enemies: <span data-name="enemies">' + card.enemies + '</span></p>';
      };

      html += '</div>';
      html += '</div>';
      html += '<div class="card_bottom card_slots">';
      html += '<div class="card_slots_inside">';

      if (Number(card.slot) > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

          if (i < card.slot) {
            html += '<span style="background: #57b371;" class="card_slot"></span>';
          } else {
            html += '<span class="card_slot"></span>';
          }
        }
      }
    }

    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    if (card.type == 16 || card.type == 14 || card.type == 31 || card.type == 27) {
      $('#card_' + card.id + ' .card_middle').remove();
      $('#card_' + card.id + ' .card_slots').css('width', '335px');
    }

    return html;
  }

  //======== CARD MANAGER ==========
  function sortCards(ar, s, t) {
    var results = [];
    var f = ar.find(function(ele) {
      if (ele[t] == s) {
        results.push(ele);
      }
    });
    return results;
  }

  $(".pun .entry-content, .pravilacontent div").each(function() {

    var h = '';
    $('img[src^="#card"]', this).each(function() {
      var npccard = $(this).attr('src');
      if (npccard != null) {
      }
    });

    if (h != '') {
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.topic-title a').text('NPC Attack');
      $(this).html(h);
    }

    var content = $(this).html();

    var el = $(this);
    content = content.replace(/#myluckynumberis(\d+)/g, function(match, capture) {

      if (!cards[capture]) {
        return "myluckynumberis #" + capture + " does not exists";
        return false;
      }

      return make_card_list(sortCards(cards, capture, "id")[0], el);
    });

    $(this).html(content);
  });
});


$(function() {

  //Indicate here the version of your forum.
  var version = "punbb";

  if (version.toLowerCase() == "phpbb2") {
    $(".postdetails span[class='staff']").closest('.postdetails').parent('td').next('td').addClass("staffbg");
  } else if (version.toLowerCase() == "phpbb3") {
    $(".postprofile span[class='staff']").closest('.postprofile').prev('.postbody').addClass("staffbg");
  } else if (version.toLowerCase() == "punbb") {
    $(".user-info span[class='staff']").closest('.postmain').addClass("staffbg");
  } else if (version.toLowerCase() == "invision") {
    $(".postprofile span[class='staff']").closest('.post-container').addClass("staffbg");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you supply a [mcve]? Currently you have A LOT of code, you should narrow it down to what causes the problem.

Comment: this is not written by me so i dont know where the issue is